# Rails, AJAX, dropzone, and carrierwave, handling redirect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, dropzone.js

```
def create
  @listing = current_user.listing.new(listing_params)
  if @listing.save
    if params[:attachment]
      params[:attachment].each do |key, val|
        @listing.attachments.create(attachment: val)
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @listing }
    end
  end
end
```

So I have that code in my create controller for the listing, and I am using dropzone JS for image and video attachments. Everything is working great as far as creating the object, however, I can't seem to figure out how to get the form to redirect to the newly created listing after the form has been submitted. The ajax request is a GET request, not a POST request because the object is already being created by the create action in the controller, making it a POST request ends up creating two objects. I've tried using render JS in the controller with a window location but nothing or I get an error saying the format is not correct. This is my JS:

```
$('#new_listing').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
  var form = $(this);
  var post_url = form.attr('action');
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
    url: post_url,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering how to change the current page, use:

`location.href = "http://www.website.com/new_listing"`

inside the `success` function to direct the browser to go to the new URL after the listing has been created. This is the same as clicking on a link with that URL. I'm guessing that the data you receive back from your server contains the new listing, which you would use to format the URL.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to that, I had to have the controller render the listing ID through JSON and passed it to the success function in JS and passed it to the location.href.

Comment: I am trying to upload more than 5 images on Amazone s3 at a time and my AJAX code is in the `success` block. What happens if I select 4 images and upload, it is working. But if I upload more than 4 images, it's uploading but not getting the callback in `success` block. Do you know why?